# Can not obtain a specific td from td_list through find_element_by_class_name or find_element_by_css_selector

Tags: selenium

When obtaining a specific td which is existed from td_list, I can not find it through class_name, and for the td, it only has a class_name and a title.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsumc.png)

Here is my code:

```
td_list = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tbody/tr/td")
for td in td_list:

print("what we got")
print(td.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='day.disabled.offday']"))

    if td.find_elements_by_css_selector("[class='day.disabled.offday']") == []:

    self.driver.refresh()
    break

    else:
    click_date = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("day.disabled.offday")
    break
```

and it keeps refreshing and outputting with:

```
what we got
[]
what we got
[]
...
```

How should I change it to obtain the specific td( class name ="day disabled offday")
Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the same with this `//*[@class='day disabled offday']` XPath ?

```
td_list = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//tbody/tr/td")
for td in td_list:

  print("what we got")
  offday_list = td.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@class='day disabled offday']")
  print(len(offday_list))
```